# dictionaries in django templates

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary that could consist of the following values

```
images={'25/02/2014': {u'Observation': [<Image: Image object>]}}
```

that is

```
{
    date:{title1:[obj1, obj2, obj3], title2:[obj1, obj2, obj3]},
    date2:{title1:[obj1, obj2, obj3]},
}
```

and I want to access the values individually and eventually the object list for each title. My code was

```
{%for date in images%}
    {%for title in images.date%} #equivalent to for title in images[date]:
        {{date}} - {{title}}
        {% for obj in images.date.title%} #equivalent to for obj in images[date][title]: but not sure
            {{obj}}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

but it won't work. It works in python for a dictionalry but not in django template. How can I access a dictionary?

Comment: http://goo.gl/Evves1 found it here...please close..Sorry!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate on the (key, values) pairs instead:

```
{% for date, data in images.items %}
  {% for title, images in data.items %} 
    {{date}} - {{title}}
    {% for image in images %} 
      {{ image }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```